# Заполнение полигона текстурой

Tags: unity3d

Как можно в `Unity` реализовать заполнение текстурой в реальном разрешении всей поверхности полигона в зависимости от его размера (без масштабирования самой текстуры)? В `3D Max` подобное можно реализовать за счет галочки `Real-World Size` и заданием размеров текстуры в сантиметрах, после чего текстура с размером в 10см. заполнит полигон в 1м. 10 раз. Есть ли что-то подобное в `Unity`?

Answer (score 0):

В `Unity` почти нет инструментов связанных с внесением изменений в 3D объекты, предполагается что вы их делаете в 3D-редакторах и всю тонкую настройку выполняете там же. Если хочется модифицировать объекты непосредственно в `Unity`, то для этого надо искать соответствующие плагины в `AssetStore`.

В настройках материала есть свойство `Tiling` оно как раз позволяет поиграться с масштабом текстуры в мапированых объектах и настроить материал под требуемый размер текстуры. Еще есть свойство `Offset`, которое позволит сместить текстуру относительно начального положения на объекте.